# How to switch off "java: variable might not have been initialized"

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
public static void main( String[  ] args ){
    int begin, end;
    try{
        begin = Integer.valueOf( args[ 1 ] );
        end = Integer.valueOf( args[ 2 ] );
    }catch( NumberFormatException conversion_error ){
        System.out.println( "Not A Number." );
        System.exit( 1 );
    }
    if( begin >= end ){
        System.out.println( "Wrong arguments. (" + begin + " >= " + end + ")" );
        System.exit(1);
    }
    System.out.print( "OK." );
    System.exit(0);
}
```

When I try to compile it, I get this error.

> Error:(13, 13) java: variable begin might not have been initialized
>   Error:(13, 22) java: variable end might not have been initialized

I understand why compiler is warning me, but the very purpose of my code is handling such situations: when variables are not initialized I shut down my program. In such case I never use them.

I think that answer is fairly simple: initialize "begin" and "end" outside "try" block, for example by immediately assigning zeros to them.

```
int begin = 0, end = 0;
```

But can I force compiler to just ignore the issue? Is there any way to switch off such inquisitive checks of my code? It's not like there is any technical problem with my program, outside of possibly wrong values of my variables.

Comment: possible duplicate of [disable an intellij compiler error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755910/disable-an-intellij-compiler-error)

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, the compiler is trying to help you avoid possible issues which might be generated by your code.  You could just intiialise values to a default, known value...

Comment: Look at the "default values" section [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). `begin` and `end` will not be assigned default values. This causes a problem since you're using them in the `if` statement. You have no choice but to initialize them.

Comment: You're asking the wrong question here. You don't want to switch it off: you want to fix your code such that that it compiles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the javadoc of `System.exit`:

> Terminates the currently running Java Virtual Machine.

Your compiler does not look ahead to figure out that the jvm will close and therfore the program will quit.

If you change `System.exit(1);` with `return;`, the compiler will recognize that at this point, your will return the control flow to the calling method. 
Since you are in the `main` method of the `Main` class of your program, it will terminate the program as well. Only now, your compiler knows about it.

You can use the following code, but be aware, that you will not send a `status code 1`  to your operating system in this case:

```
public static void main( String[  ] args ) {

try{
    final int begin = Integer.valueOf( args[ 1 ] );
    final int end = Integer.valueOf( args[ 2 ] );

    if( begin >= end ) {
        System.out.println( "Wrong arguments. (" + begin + " >= " + end + ")" );
        System.exit(1);
    }

} catch( NumberFormatException conversion_error ) {
    System.out.println( "Not A Number." );
    return;
}

System.out.print( "OK." );
System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: The correct way to fix it is to put all the code that uses `begin` and `end` inside the `try` block, where it should have been in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

No. You can't switch it off. The compiler insists that you don't use uninitialized variables. It is a [rule of Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-16.html).

You need to fix your code. Specifically, code that depends on the success of code in a prior `try` block should be inside that `try` block.

Answer (score 0):

Like the others say, you don't disable the error, you fix the error in your code. I suggest this work-around

```
public static void main( String[  ] args ){
    int begin, end;
    try{
        begin = Integer.valueOf( args[ 1 ] );
        end = Integer.valueOf( args[ 2 ] );

        if( begin >= end ){
            System.out.println( "Wrong arguments. (" + begin + " >= " + end + ")" );
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.out.print( "OK." );
        System.exit(0);
    }catch( NumberFormatException conversion_error ){
        System.out.println( "Not A Number." );
        System.exit( 1 );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are arguably legitimate reasons that you may want to ignore/suppress a variable may not be initialized warning... for example, when you are initializing the variable in an @Before method in a test.  In that case, you can use: `@SuppressWarnings("InstanceVariableMayNotBeInitialized")`

Note: I would add a ending comment explaining why

`@SuppressWarnings("InstanceVariableMayNotBeInitialized") // Initialized in @Before`

Comment: The question is about an error, not a warning, which arises with local variables, not instance variables.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this happened to you:

- You want to use a variable in a static method.
- You have something like a loop or switch construct, so you can't figure out where to initialise things because of block scope and curly braces.
- The answer is to either:

  - 1 Declare the variables as static
  - 2 Create an instance of the class with properties defined at the class level instead.

    - Then call a method on that class instance.
    - So you end up with something like this:

```
public class Solution {
    private int i;
    private double d;
    private String s;
    private Solution() {
        i = 0;
        d = 0.0;
        s = null;
    }
    private void processInput() {
       /* using i in here now, instead of i in main
        * since that's the equivalent of this.i now instead
        * ... unless you defined int i in the method!
        */
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solution s = new Solution();
        s.processInput();
    }
}
```

- You may also be able to get away without introducing class level properties, by refactoring too, and breaking things down into methods that return types and all the types are within the same scoped block.